# FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain Code=3

Tags: ios, compiler-errors, ios-simulator, watchkit, apple-watch

I just added a Watch app to my project and try :

```
override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
        super.awakeWithContext(context)
        let res =  WKInterfaceController.openParentApplication(["key" : "value"]) { (replyInfo, error) -> Void in
            print("replyInfo : \(replyInfo) + error \(error)")
        }
        print(res) // true here
    }
```

In my AppDelegate I wrote :

```
func application(application: UIApplication, handleWatchKitExtensionRequest userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]?, reply: ([NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Void) {
        reply(["replyKey" : "replyValue"]);
    }
```

When I launch the Watch app I just have :

> replyInfo : [:] + error Optional(Error
>   Domain=FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain Code=3 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain eor 3.)")

[image: Screenshot for error message]

Is it due to the simulator ? Do you know what am doing wrong ?

Thanks !

Comment: I have the same problem with xcode 7.0 beta 3. When i use xcode 6.3, it works well. I hope, it can help you.

Comment: Ok thx. I'll wait next beta and update this post

Comment: I had this problem after installing xcode 7.1....xcode sucks, ios9 sucks..apple sucks..

Comment: If you have this problem on a physical device (as opposed to the simulator), see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34384015/35690).

Answer (score 97, accepted):

iOS Simulator -> Reset Contents and Settings...

Worked for me

**iOS Simulator -> Reset Contents and Settings... -> Reset**

Comment: Thanks, it does it for an ios app as well.

Comment: Didn't worked for me..I'm using Xcode 6.4 on OS X 10.11.1. I cannot migrate to Xcode 7.1 due to technical issues. Any other fix?

Comment: Same scenario ... Xcode 6.4, OS X 10.11.1, Xcode 7 with an internal bug in IB disabling me from using latest Xcode. After reverting back to Xcode 6.4, dozens of simulators appeared in it, so I wiped out all of them, and used Xcode to resurrect just iOS 7.1 ones. A now this.

Comment: This solution didn't work for me. I have OS X 10.11.1. and both Xcode 6.4 / 7.1.1 with iOS 8.4, 9.0 and 9.1 simulator (running of MacBook Pro 2015)

Comment: Did as above except I quit the simulator and then quit Xcode, relaunched and ran without issue.

Comment: Killing the simulator and clearing the project (Shift+cmd+K ) and rerunning did the trick for me.

Comment: iOs 9 and Xcode 7.1 , Clean project, and resetting simulator worked.

Answer (score 28):

---

## *Keep Your Settings*

---

Restart simulator:

- Click on Simulator app
- **Simulator > Quit Simulator** *or* `CMD + Q`
- Click on xcode
- **Project > Run** *or* `CMD + R`

Answer (score 6):

For those using real hardware and not the simulator, I had this issue. The problem is I'd selected my individual developer account as my code signer. In doing so, I had to go to:

**Settings > General > Profiles > Device Management > (my email)**

and then tap the **Trust (my email)** to trust my individual account.

After I did this, cmd-R ran my code on my watch/phone just fine.

Comment: Profiles was empty for my device, but following answer helped - https://stackoverflow.com/a/34384069/6843499

Answer (score 1):

Try returning to the view controller and running again in the simulator; it worked for me in Xcode 7.2.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this when running on the actual watch. Turned out to be caused by the developer account not being trusted on the iPhone. Settings->Device Management->...

Answer (score 0):

in react native just uninstall the **`pods and podfile.lock`**  and reinstall the pods through command

```
cd ios && pod install
```