# The operation couldn’t be completed. (FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain error 3.)

Tags: swift, xcode7

I was just building and running an app a few minutes ago and now I am receiving the error "The operation couldn’t be completed. (FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain error 3.)" does anyone know what this means?

Thanks

I am using xcode7 and swift

Comment: I'm getting this too, but I have no idea why!

Comment: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31438999/fbsopenapplicationerrordomain-code-3) help

Comment: looks like it worked

Answer (score 2):

Reset iOS simulator.

```
Simulator > Reset content and settings... > Reset
```

It worked for me. 
This is not an error, Sometimes Xcode sdk behaves abnormally as its compiler do stuck while performing actions.
As Simulator is a virtual devices, It also stuck at some point.
So do reset as guided by above instructions. Hope it will help.
Happy coding...