# FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain error 3 when trying to launch a watch kit app on a physical device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, apple-watch

I get the same problem that is described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31438999/fbsopenapplicationerrordomain-code-3). However, that problem dealt with the iOS simulator, not a physical device.

I'm not using the iOS Simulator. I'm deploying to an iPhone + Apple Watch.

If I attempt to run it on the simulator, it works just fine.

On the "Running WatchKit App on Apple Watch" build step, I get the following error:

> **Error Launching 'WatchKit Extension'**
> The operation couldn’t be completed. (FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain error 3.)

---

#### What I've tried:

I tried **reseting the iOS simulator** and then running it on the device (not sure how that would help), but I still got the same error message.

I tried going in to iOS Settings > General > Device Management and **ensuring that the app is "Verified".**

**Restarting Xcode** didn't help either.

**Deleting the app and reinstalling** doesn't help.

I tried **running the iOS app** once to ensure there are no permissions issues on that end.

Xcode: 7.2
iPhone: iOS 9.2
Apple Watch: watchOS 2.1

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This was a permissions issue on the Apple Watch.

To fix:

1. Launch the app once manually (not through Xcode).

   You will see the following message:

   > **Untrusted App Developer**
   >   Do you trust the developer "..." to run apps on your Apple Watch?
   >   [Trust]
   >   [Don't Trust]
2. Tap Trust.
3. Now you can run the app through Xcode with no issues.

Answer (score 2):

Had same issue:

1. Go to settings on iphone
2. General > Device management
3. choose your developer app from list
4. click on trust