# There is a problem with my flutter application when I try to run it on xcode it build successfully but the app crash directly

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, multithreading, signals

I have tried to run it using the emulator on the xcode and the terminal it didn't worked  and that is the output

[image]

[image]

```
**
```

> and this is the pubspec file:
> name: cash description: A new Flutter project.
>
> ## The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
>
> ## pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages. publish_to: "none" # Remove this line if you wish to publish to
>
> pub.dev
>
> ## The following defines the version and build number for your application.
>
> ## A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
>
> ## followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
>
> ## Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
>
> ## build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
>
> ## In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
>
> ## In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
>
> ## Read more about iOS versioning at version: 1.0.0+1 environment:   sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0" dependencies:   flutter:
>
> ```
> sdk: flutter   # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.   # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style
> ```
>
> icons.   shared_preferences: ^2.0.5   http: ^0.13.2   provider: ^6.0.3
> image_picker: ^0.8.5   document_scanner_flutter: ^0.2.3
> connectivity_wrapper: ^1.1.0   group_radio_button: ^1.2.0
> another_flushbar: ^1.10.29   syncfusion_flutter_charts: ^20.1.59
> file_picker: ^4.6.1 dev_dependencies:   flutter_test:
> sdk: flutter
>
> ## The following section is specific to Flutter. flutter:   # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is   # included
>
> with your application, so that you can use the icons in   # the
> material Icons class.   uses-material-design: true   # To add assets
> to your application, add an assets section, like this:   assets:
> - assets/image/bg32.jpg
> - assets/image/group_87.jpg
> - assets/image/payment.png
> - assets/image/group_10.png
> - assets/image/group_6.png
> - assets/image/group_8.png
> - assets/image/calendar.png
> - assets/image/group_100.png
> - assets/image/bottom_arrow.png
> - assets/image/approve.png
> - assets/image/fatoora.jpg
> - assets/image/chart.jpg   #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg   # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants",
> see   # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies,
> see   # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section
> here,   # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should
> have a   # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key
> with a   # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font.
> For   # example:   fonts:
> - family: Tajawalen
> fonts:
> - asset: assets/fonts/TajawalRegular.ttf
> - asset: assets/fonts/TajawalBold.ttf
> weight: 700   #   - family: Trajan Pro   #     fonts:   #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf   #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf   #         weight: 700   #   # For details
> regarding fonts from package dependencies,

**

Comment: Are you using firebase?

Comment: no I am not using firebase

Comment: Can you include pubspec here please

Comment: does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31438999/fbsopenapplicationerrordomain-code-3

Comment: In future please don't take screenshots of your code and errors. Instead you should include them in your question as text with code markups. That way it is easier for people to work with it. [ask]

Comment: I added the pubspec.yaml file